# Are interfaces ensured in the OOP node.js framework Danf?

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, frameworks, danf

In Danf, if I define two classes like that:

```
// lib/server/listener.js

'use strict';

/**
 * Expose `Listener`.
 */
module.exports = Listener;

/**
 * Initialize a new listener.
 */
function Listener() {
    this._listener;
}

Listener.defineImplementedInterfaces(['listener']);

/**
 * @interface {listener}
 */
Listener.prototype.update = function() {
    // Do something...

    this.doUpdate();
}

Listener.prototype.doUpdate = function() {
    // Do something...
}
```

---

```
// lib/server/notifier.js

'use strict';

/**
 * Expose `Notifier`.
 */
module.exports = Notifier;

/**
 * Initialize a new notifier.
 */
function Notifier() {
    this._listener;
}

Notifier.defineImplementedInterfaces(['notifier']);

Notifier.defineDependency('_listener', 'listener');

/**
 * @interface {notifier}
 */
Notifier.prototype.notify = function(notifier) {
    listener.update();
    // listener.doUpdate(); // Is it possible?
}

Object.defineProperty(Notifier.prototype, 'listener', {
    set: function(listener) { this._listener = listener; }
});
```

With the following config:

```
// config/server/config/interfaces.js

'use strict';

module.exports = {
    listener: {
        methods: {
            update: {
                arguments: ['string/value']
            }
        }
    },
    notifier: {
        methods: {
            notify: {}
        }
    }
};
```

---

```
// config/server/config/services.js

'use strict';

module.exports = {
    listener: {
        class: 'listener'
    },
    notifier: {
        class: 'notifier',
        properties: {
            listener: '#listener#'
        }
    }
};
```

Would I be able to call the method "doUpdate" of the listener in the notifier even if I don't specify it in the interface "listener"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [Danf](https://github.com/gnodi/danf), when you define `Notifier.defineDependency('_listener', 'listener');`, a proxy is created on the listener used by the notifier. This proxy prevent you to use anything else than what it is specified in the interface `listener`.

To sum up, yes the interfaces are ensured, no you won't be able to call method `doUpdate` in the notifier.

However, as this feature takes a lot of performances (because it is not a built in javascript feature), it is only [enabled in debug mode](https://github.com/gnodi/danf/blob/master/doc/use/app.md).